# How can I get my local host test server to stop autofilling a username and password in React?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, autofill

I have deleted all of my cookies, cache is disabled, I don't have any saved passwords in chrome.

Yet I still have the dummy email username/password I used previously autofilling every single time I click to fill out log in/password info on any react app I make.

Does someone know how to get rid of this?

All I get is the option to click "Manage Passwords" which leads chrome to showing me I have no saved passwords!

It's really irritating.

Comment: Use [autoComplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) attribute. You need to set it `off`.

Comment: Hi this doesn't solve my problem since the problem is no matter what I do in any react application this email/password combo autofills.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a saved username, use the "Down" arrow on your keyboard to highlight that username, and then press "Shift-Delete".

[Shift-Delete method source](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/check-usernames-saved-chrome-67836.html)

Comment: This didn't work for me on a mac (fn backspace were the mac instructions)